# Unity .gitignore does not exclude the whole directory

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, github, filesystems, gitignore

### Steps to reproduce:

1. I am using a [stable gitignore unity file](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Unity.gitignore)
2. Run `git rm -r --cached .` before recommitting gitignore file changes
3. Run `git add .`
4. The output of `git status --ignored` yields mixed results (see "*scr A*" below) - **some files in the excluded directory do not get ignored** and some do

### Key points:

- Large files I'm not interested in are not getting ignored (such as Unity's [build engine "Bee"](https://forum.unity.com/threads/question-what-is-that-bee-stuff.1124242/#:%7E:text=Unity%20Technologies&text=Bee%20is%20our%20build%20backend,officially%20supported%20Linux%20Editor%20release.) file) and break my `git push` attempts. Using GitHub.
- I've created an empty repo where the big files where never pushed before and still run into the same issue on the first upload with the above .gitignore file
- The .gitignore file resides in the root of my project (same level as the Unity project name and .git init dir)
- I tried excluding the specific files which also did not work
- Git version 2.31.0.windows.1, Unity version 2022.1.4f1

*scr A*:
[image]

Comment: See [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1256452) (and also more generally [ask]). I can't read the tiny text in the image, but I will note that `.gitignore` has nothing to do with *large* files. It affects only *untracked* files, making Git shut up about them, but in a new repository, all files will be untracked, so existing tracked files are probably not the issue here. (Also your `git rm --cached` would have solved that.) So it's not a `.gitignore` issue.

Comment: If you need large files to go into commits, consider setting up Git-LFS. If you *don't* need large files to go into the commits at all, you may need to add these to the `.gitignore`: the "stable" .gitignore you're using may not list them (for whatever reason).

Comment: I tried excluding the specfic files as well, but that did not fix the issue. Git would try uploading them anyway. Plus all the large files were under the excluded /Library directory.

Comment: That text is still unreadable, but at the red circle-ish thing around the green text, it really looks like it says something like "mineLIbrary", not "Library".

Comment: `/Libary/` in your `.gitignore` file says ignore that directory when it is found at the root of your repo.  `/mind/Library` is not ignored by your `.gitignore` file. `.gradle`, on the other hand, is ignored at any depth by a different rule in your `.gitignore` file.

Comment: @joanis changing the directories for ´´´/mind/Library´´´ produced the same error

Comment: I cannot reproduce that problem. If I add `/mind/Library` in a test `.gitignore` file, the contents of that folder get ignored for me.

Comment: Could you detail what you do when you start from scratch with an empty repo and it's not working?